# What is the relationship between batch size, timestep and error in LSTM (Keras)?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, lstm-stateful

Let,

`Sample Size = 100` (X1,X2,...,X100)

`Timesteps = 5`

`Input Feature = 10`

**Error Calculation:**

How is the error calculation done when **batch size = Sample size**?
My understanding: I will insert `X1,X2,X3,X4,X5` into LSTM and get an output after `5` timesteps, say `Y1`.

Error `E1 = X6 - Y1`. Similarly I will calculate `E2,E3,...,E95`.

`Actual Error = E1+E2+....+E95`. This will be used to update weights.

Is it correct?

**Error for Batch:**

Based on above understanding. If `batch size = 10`. Then only `E1,E2,E3,E4 and E5` will be used to calculate actual error. This will be used to update weights.

**Batching in stateful LSTM:**

Batches allows the model to allow parallelism where each entity in the batch calculates its error and then all the errors are summed. How does LSTM achieve parallelism within a batch if the LSTM is stateful (the hidden states of previous sequence are used to initialize the hidden states of next sequence, is this understanding of Satetful correct?) ?

References:

[LSTM Batches vs Timesteps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010966/lstm-batches-vs-timesteps)

[Understanding Keras LSTMs: Role of Batch-size and Statefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491737/understanding-keras-lstms-role-of-batch-size-and-statefulness)

[doubts regarding batch size and time steps in RNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381450/doubts-regarding-batch-size-and-time-steps-in-rnn)

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions!

Comment: The first 3 questions are linked. 4th one could be a seperate one. Edit 1: It should make more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Batch size effect on LSTM:** For batch size 1 the model takes 1 input at each timestep. For batch size n, model takes n input at each Timestep

[image: Image for clarification Credit: Deeplearning.ai]

**Error Calculation part mentioned in question**:  It is the error calculation for batch size 1.

**Error for a batch:** Sum up the error for each element of the batch to get the final error

**Batching in Stateful LSTM:** My understanding of parallelism was incorrect. Parallelism is done within batch not across them.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly: timesteps (dim 1 of the input data) is the length of the RNN; batch_size (dim 0 of the input data) is the number of runs computed at the same time (parallelism). If I set stateful=True, I'm propagating the "memory" hidden data between batches, but not within a batch. So if I want to train a perfectly stateful RNN, I should set timesteps as high as the hardware allows, and batch_size = 1? Is this correct?

Comment: I do not have much clarity about stateful RNNs as I never used it much. However, I wrote this blog a couple of years later, and should help you with understanding batch, timestep, and features using simple python code
https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/a-very-simple-lstm-6ec4cb6286b6